# Sigin my app with Google Account in Android

Tags: android, google-plus, google-account

I have learned that there are many ways to sign in app with Google Account.
Here are two ways:

1. Use `AccountManager.java` ,
   **GOOD**: can get user's email address and authToken.
   **BAD**: can not get user's avatar and nickname.
2. Use `Google+ Api`:
   **GOOD**: can get user's  all info , but email address.
   **BAD**: no email address, and the view's style is not matching to my app.

**QUESTION**:

1 .How can i get avatar and nickname by using only `AccountManager` ?

2. Is the Google+ Api's view be changed ? Any documents?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the Email address via the Google+ API. You need to add the appropriate scopes and permission.

The scopes are

```
Scopes.PROFILE
Scopes.EMAIL
```

And you need the following permission

```
android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS
```

Then you can retrieve the Email address with the AccountApi

```
Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(googleApiClient)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reference [this guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/people) from google doc.
After signin, handle result then get user information.